# How do I add a int variable to itself in C?

Tags: c

Here is the beginning to a very basic calculator I'm making to get some practice in C. To explain what I'm trying to do, I'm simply trying to get it so that after each time this code loops it adds the 'num1' variable, in turn allowing you to add as many numbers as you'd like. Like i said this serves no real porous I'm just new to C and looking to practice a bit.

Now to give an example of where this code goes wrong, if i want to add 4 numbers (lets say just 1+2+3+4) the answer would always end up being 3 for some reason. Now i realize that some of the code more then likely makes me seem kinda stupid... For example,

```
num3 = num2 + num1;
        num3 = num1;
```

then looping back and just doing that again, but i stress that anything that is stupidly wrong is either due to my desperate changes to the code in an attempt to get it to work, or just because im new. Thanks to all who can help me with this.

```
float num1, num2, num3;
int loop1 = 0;
int loop2 = 0;
int choice;

printf("Which would you like to do?\n1) Add.\n2) Subtract.\n3) Multiply.\n4) Divide.\n");
scanf("%i", &choice);

switch(choice){

    case 1:
        printf("How many numbers would you like to add?: ");
        scanf("%i", &loop2);
        while (loop1 < loop2){
        printf("Pleas enter a number: ");
        scanf("%f", &num1);
        printf("Pleas enter a number: ");
        scanf("%f", &num2);
        num3 = num2 + num1;
        num3 = num1;
        loop1 ++;
        loop1 ++;}
        printf("%f", num1);
        break;
```

Comment: `num3 = num2 + num1;` should be `num3 += num2 + num1;` so every time you go into the loop you add to the previous addition. Also remove `num3 = num1;` you are messing up your addition!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running these lines:

```
    num3 = num2 + num1;
    num3 = num1;
```

Causes you to overwrite your sum continuously.  What you want to do is initialize `num3` to zero before your loop, and then just add each number in turn.  Something like this example, to modify your code as minimally as possible:

```
num3 = 0;
while (loop1 < loop2)
{
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num1);
    num3 += num1;
    loop1++;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, very good thank you very much. Thanks for helping out someone who is green as can be haha. If I was a high enough rank I'd up-vote your answer.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.  If you "accept" the answer, you'll get a little rep bump, and that should help you on your way.

Comment: There we go. Thanks for taking time out of your day to help me. :)